# FlashDevelop and Flash 11 Incubator

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, haxe

How can i start coding Flash 11 using ActionScript3 or Haxe with FlashDevelop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for stupid question, solution was pretty easy.

1. [Download Flash 11 Incubator](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplatformruntimes_incubator.html)
2. [Download FlexSDK 4.5](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4.5) and extract it somewhere
3. [Download flashplayer_inc_playerglobal_022711](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashplatformruntimes/incubator/flashplayer_inc_playerglobal_022711.swc)
4. Make folder "10.1" inside {FlexSDK}/frameworks/libs/player
5. copy flashplayer_inc_playerglobal_022711.swc into new "10.1" folder and rename file to playerglobal.swc
6. Point FlashDevelop to FlexSDK 4.5
7. Set Project Target to 10.1
8. Add this **"-swf-version=13"** to Additional Compiler Option in project settings window

There is no official standalone Flash player 11 but you can use [Unofficial one](http://code.google.com/p/ascensionsystems/downloads/list)