# How to compile for Flash 11 with CS4

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

Anyone know a way to build to Flash 11 using the CS4 IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

http://pgstudios.org/index.php?b=compiling-for-flash-player-11-in-flash-pro-cs5

If it doesn't work, I sugest FlashDevelop instead. You're not going to be using a metric ton of MovieClips if you are specifically targeting Flash 11 today, so just embed your .swc files or .swf files directly into flex (create them with Flash CS4) and program in there.

Nice thing about FlashDevelop is that it's 1) completely free 2) flex has incremental compiling available, flash cs4 does not, which means i would never ever in a thousand years go back to flash for fp11 GPU accelerated content. Absolutely pointless and counter productive.

[FlashDevelop and Flash 11 Incubator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975379/flashdevelop-and-flash-11-incubator)

Follow this, it's old now but it's more or less the way it's done. I can't seem to find those old step by step tutorials on how to do this. You'll need to setup paths to the playeglobal.swc directly in the project in FlashDevelop, it won't work for global paths.

Also, Philipe here says that you can just target FP11 now and since Flash Player is live from 4 days ago the latest FlexSDK might suport it out of the box so philipe's comment on this forum probably talks about the latest FlexSDK.

http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=8815

Sorry, I can't find those older much better and easier to understand fp11 setup tutorials for FlashDevelop...

Use this link bellow for reference on how to setup swf-version = 13 though it seems it's not needed anymore:

http://www.swfgeek.net/2011/02/27/molehill-3d-apis-for-adobe-flash-player-and-adobe-air/

Feel free to ask here if you get stuck on some part of FlashDevelop setup. I can't help you for CS4, sorry.

Also, only standalone fp11 players will work, if you get Context3D runtime error it means you are playing the file in fp10 or bellow.

Edit: Found the good old fp11 stage3d tutorial for flashdevelop. This should get you started out of the box.
http://www.mclelun.com/blog/2011/08/flashdevelop-stage3d-away3d/

Comment: Hmmm seems like I need to finally drop CS4 for flex...  Just really like the lazy use of combining interface with coding but I know that's bad way of programming better separate interface from logic..  It just doesn't make a lot of sense that the product adobe offers is not even close to the free version..  And thanks for all the info!

Comment: you don't have to drop anything, it will stil be available as a .swc/swf, just keep recompiling the interface... You don't even have to move all of the code out of the timeline. Though since .swc/.swf's are encapsulated, it's prudent to move most of the "custom" app code into flex.