# How do I compile to Flash 11 (even version) with Adobe Flash CS6?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, compilation, adobe, version

I need to compile to an even version of Flash due to server issues (I'm not a back-end developer, nor do I have access to the server in any way). I can publish to 9, 10, or 11, but have a very small size limit and would like to use the improved compression available starting with 11. I'm also using the PerspectiveProjection to fix some 3d rotation issues that appear otherwise.

I can only use Flash CS6 (or the command-line) and not Flex Builder or any other program. CS6 has a drop-down menu with the only (AS3-compatible) options as 9, 10.3, 11.1, 11.2, 11.3, and 11.4.

Is there any way I can compile to Flash Player 11.0?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693720/how-to-compile-for-flash-11-with-cs4

Comment: That one allowed (and received) an answer outside of any Creative Suite and also addressed CS4. It also did not require that it be an even version of Flash Player.

This one required (and received) an answer that applied to CS6 and Flash Player 11.0, rather than Flash Player 11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1: click this site: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html

2:  download Playerglobal.swc archives **Flash Player 11.0 (329 KB)**

3:  copy to this path

Mac: /Applications/Adobe Flash CS6/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/FP11.0/**playerglobal.swc**

[image]

Win: /Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/FP11.0/

4: make a FlashPlayer11_0.xml

Mac: /Applications/Adobe Flash CS6/Common/Configuration/Players/

[image]

Win: /Common/Configuration/Players/

5: copy & paste following xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<players>
  <player id="FlashPlayer11.0" version="13" asversion="3">
   <name>Flash Player 11.0</name>
   <path builtin="true"/>
   <path menuSortCategory="10"/>
   <path platform="WIN">Device Central/adcdl.exe</path>
   <path platform="MAC">Device Central/adcdl</path>
   <playerDefinitionPath as2="$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP10;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP9;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP8;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP7" as3="$(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/FP11.0/playerglobal.swc" />
   <feature name="multiScreenPublish"               supported="true" />
   <feature name="mobileAuthoringIntegration"           supported="true" />
   <feature name="deviceSound"                  supported="false"/>
   <feature name="exportStreamingSound"         supported="true"/>
   <feature name="exportEventSound"             supported="true"/>
   <feature name="FSCommand2"                   supported="false"/>
   <feature name="gradient_linearRGB"           supported="true" />
   <feature name="gradient_overflow"            supported="true" />
   <feature name="shape_strokeHint"             supported="true" />
   <feature name="shape_cap"                supported="true" />
   <feature name="shape_join"               supported="true" />
   <feature name="shape_mitre"              supported="true" />
   <feature name="shape_scale"              supported="true" />
   <feature name="linkage_exportForActionscript"    supported="true" />
   <feature name="linkage_exportForRuntimeSharing"  supported="true" />
   <feature name="linkage_exportInFirstFrame"       supported="true" />
   <feature name="linkage_importForRuntimeSharing"  supported="true" />
   <feature name="linkage_importAndAddToCache"      supported="false" />
   <feature name="publish_localPlaybackSecurity"    supported="true" />
   <feature name="publish_hardwareAcceleration"     supported="true" />
   <feature name="symbol_blendMode"             supported="true" /> 
   <feature name="actionScript_documentClass"       supported="true" />
   <feature name="symbol_blendMode"             supported="true" />
   <feature name="filters"              supported="true" />
   <feature name="component_binding"            supported="true" />
   <feature name="component_schema"             supported="true" />
   <feature name="screens"              supported="true" />
   <feature name="video"                supported="true" />
   <feature name="deviceVideo"              supported="false"/>
   <feature name="accessibility"            supported="true" />
   <feature name="dynamic_text_kerning"         supported="true" />
   <feature name="static_text_charwidth_nondeviceFont"  supported="true" /> 
   <feature name="static_text_charwidth_deviceFont" supported="true" />
   <feature name="advanced_anti_alias_text"         supported="true" /> 
   <feature name="nine_slice_scaling"           supported="true" />
   <feature name="runtimeNumberMinMax"          supported="true" />
   <feature name="use8kSampleRate"                      supported="true" />
   <feature name="useDefineFont4ForDeviceText"          supported="true" />
   <feature name="useDefineFont4ForEmbeddedFonts"       supported="true" />
   <feature name="textLayoutFramework"       supported="true" />
   <feature name="document_class"                   supported="true" />
   <encodingPresets>
        <preset uuid="da5cac1a-417a-4d86-b7f7-ef21010a5d7d"  name="FLV - Match Source Attributes (High Quality)" ext="flv" default="true"/>
    </encodingPresets>

   <testmenu> 
    <menu name="ID_testInFlash" default="true"/>
    <menu name="ID_testInDeviceCentral" />
   </testmenu>

   <debugmenu>
    <menu name="ID_debugtInFlash" default="true"/> 
    <menu name="ID_debugInDeviceCentral"/> 
  </debugmenu>


   </player>
</players>
```

6: Restart Flash CS6. and Happy Coding! :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That worked. One note, however. I had to rename the file to playerglobal.swc instead of playerglobal11_0.swc.